# Python pool map issue - list of lists

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to apply multiprocessing to my code. However, I am facing an issue when passing a list of lists of lists. I have the following simplified code

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, Process

def preprocess(tsk, passedlist, tsklist):

    tsklist[tsk] = tsk
    passedlist[tsk][0] = tsk

    return tsklist, passedlist


if __name__ == "__main__": 

    Machines = 30
    Tasks = 20
    manager = Manager()

    tsklist = [[] for tsk in range(Tasks)]
    list1 = [[[] for mch in range(Machines)] for tsk in range(Tasks)]
    tsklist = manager.list(tsklist)
    list1 = manager.list(list1)

    pool = Pool(processes = 3)

    opr_list = [(tsk, list1, tsklist) for tsk in range(Tasks)]

    results = list(pool.starmap(preprocess, opr_list))

    tsklist = list(results[0][0])
    list1 = list(results[0][1])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(tsklist[1])
    print(list1[1][0])
```

I am getting the output of list1[1][0] = [] although it should be 1. Is there something I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Because this is creating a list of lists of lists. But your final statement `print(list1[1][0])` only accesses a depth of 2

I indented your list comprehension so it's easier to tell.

```
list1 = [
    [
        [] for mch in range(Machines)
    ] for tsk in range(Tasks)
]
```

What is your goal -- What is the purpose of generating empty lists, instead of appending as you go? Because there's probably an easier way.

Comment: In the function, I am also using depth of 2 so it should print the same output. It works when I don't use multiprocessing. Those empty lists will be filled inside the function but I am simplifying it here.